# Why is the Namespace "IUnityRenderPipeline" Suddenly Missing from the Vuforia Script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I've been working in Unity the last month or so.  I've gotten a few iterations of a basic AR application worked up but I've updated Unity and now my code is throwing all sorts of errors.

Last week my app was working fine when building to my Pixel phone.  Now that I've updated to Unity 2018.3.9, Vuforia 8.1 is now missing the name space mentioned in the title.  Does anyone have any information on this?

The app will play correctly if I restart Unity up until I try to build the application to the phone.  Once I build and it fails I can't replay the application due to compiler errors.

I've typed in different namespaces in the Vuforia Script and have checked my script.  Mine is the same script I've used in previous versions with zero issues.  I have Vuforia in the namespace but the issue appears to be coming form the Vuforia inherent script instead.

Here's the section of the Vuforia Code that appears to have the most bugs:

```
\\\\

namespace Vuforia.UnityCompiled
{
    public class RuntimeOpenSourceInitializer
    {
        static IUnityCompiledFacade sFacade;

        [RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod(RuntimeInitializeLoadType.BeforeSceneLoad)]
        static void OnRuntimeMethodLoad()
        {
            InitializeFacade();
        }

        static void InitializeFacade()
        {
            if (sFacade != null) return;

            sFacade = new OpenSourceUnityCompiledFacade();
            UnityCompiledFacade.Instance = sFacade;
        }

        class OpenSourceUnityCompiledFacade : IUnityCompiledFacade
        {
            readonly IUnityRenderPipeline mUnityRenderPipeline = new UnityRenderPipeline();

            public IUnityRenderPipeline UnityRenderPipeline
            {
                get { return mUnityRenderPipeline; }
            }
        }

        class UnityRenderPipeline : IUnityRenderPipeline
        {
            public event Action<Camera[]> BeginFrameRendering;
            public event Action<Camera> BeginCameraRendering;

            public UnityRenderPipeline()

\\\\\
```

I'm not versed enough in C# to know the fine tunings of QC'ing the code other than the immediate lack of ";" in a lot of these lines.

What the app should be doing is building correctly to my phone.  Once there it's an application that reads a sketch I drew, and shows a model or several renderings of the space based on the image target and virtual buttons placed in Unity.

Comment: Are you getting an error?  `IUnityRenderPipeline` does not look like a namespace.  It seems to be an interface since your class `UnityRenderPipeline` is implementing it.

Comment: And the reason its missing is likely because the name changed to something else, which has happened a lot with the render pipeline stuff as a result of the Lightweight Render Pipeline. Complain to Vuforia.

Comment: Yes I am getting an error.  Unity is recognizing it as a Namespace error.  CS0246 is the error code but people say the fix for that is to add "using Vuforia" to the user's script.  However this is the Vuforia script so it is definitely a Vuforia issue.  But it only occured after updating Unity lol

Comment: UPDATE:  So I didn't know this..  Unity updates but doesn't recognize any Vuforia updates..  So I updated Vuforia and then the new version of Unity didn't recognize that...  it's fixed now.  Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

**Hello**

Not sure how you created your app, but these errors look similar to ones you'd get if there was a mismatch between the Engine SDK version and the Vuforia samples.  As the SDK evolves and APIs are created/changes, so do the samples to be compatible with them. Here's how you can check the versions of both (assuming you used Vuforia samples resources):

**- SDK version: Unity Editor->Window->Vuforia Configuration.**
 **- Samples version: Unity Editor->Project window: Assets/Vuforia/version.**
also, you can delete the old version of Vuforia and re-import from the Package Manager in Unity.

**Thanks,**